# how to pass data from node.js to local javascript, keeping array capabilities?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

how to pass data from node.js to local javascript, keeping array capabilities?

```
const query = db.query(sql, post, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else if (results.length >= 1) {
            
            console.log(results);
            const listResults = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                
                listResults.push(results[i].ENwords);
                listResults.push(results[i].PLwords);
            }
            
            res.render('flashcards', {layout: 'flashcards', listResults});
```

in flashcard.ejs:

```
<script>

let listWords = <%= listResults %>;
console.log(listWords);

</script>
```

I get an error that the first item in the list is "is not defined".

I've also tried this. This works but the value is no longer an array:

```
<script>

let listWords = "<%= listResults %>";
console.log(listWords);

</script>
```

In this particular case, reworking these values ​​is pointless, because different data are stored there and it is not possible to divide them in an appropriate way to make a new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stringify the array in Node.js

```
let listWords = <%- JSON.stringify(listResults) %>;
```

`JSON.stringify` creates a JSON representation of the string and JSON can be used as array literal.

Comment: @marcin I fixed my answer. `<%=` escapes special HTML characters. `<%-` outputs the unescaped value into the template